# insert to the treeview

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

in this segment of code i created a treeview tree,
when the button save is clicked the content of the entries are insert to the tree
,but when i click this button nothing done!
,and when i scroll down the last three items didn't show on the tree

```
        self.tree=ttk.Treeview(data, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), show='headings',height=10)
        self.tree.pack(side='left')
        self.tree.place(x=0, y=0)
        
        self.tree.heading(1, text='ID')
        self.tree.heading(2, text='first name')
        self.tree.heading(3, text='last name')
        self.tree.heading(4, text='age')
        self.tree.heading(5, text='gender')
        self.tree.heading(6, text='email')
        self.tree.heading(7, text='salary')

        cursor=self.getInfofromDB()
        for i in cursor:
            print(i)
            self.tree.insert('', 'end',  value=i)

        #set the width of the columns
        self.tree.column(1, width=50)
        self.tree.column(2, width=200)
        self.tree.column(3, width=200)
        self.tree.column(4, width=125)
        self.tree.column(5, width=135)
        self.tree.column(6, width=250)
        self.tree.column(7, width=130)



        #create a vertical scrollbar
        yscrollbar=ttk.Scrollbar(data, orient='vertical',
                                 command=self.tree.yview)
        yscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')


        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
    def button_save(self):
        #insert to the database
        u.Insert(self.first_name_entry.get(),
                 self.last_name_entry.get(),
                 self.age_entry.get(),
                 self.gender_var.get(),
                 self.email_entry.get(),
                 self.salary_entry.get())
        if self.gender_var==0:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(self.first_name_entry.get(),
                                                self.last_name_entry.get(),
                                                self.age_entry.get(),
                                                'male',
                                                self.email_entry.get(),
                                                self.salary_entry.get()))
        elif self.gender_var==1:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(self.first_name_entry.get(),
                                                self.last_name_entry.get(),
                                                self.age_entry.get(),
                                                'female',
                                                self.email_entry.get(),
                                                self.salary_entry.get()))
```

Comment: try self.gender_var.get()

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look on this bit of code here:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def p_var():
    print(f'_var is {_var}')
    print(f'_var.get() is {_var.get()}')

_var = tk.IntVar()
_var.set(1)
b = tk.Button(root, text='exampel',
              command = p_var
              )
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The Output of this is:

```
_var is PY_VAR0
_var.get() is 1
```

So as you may notice, the _var is an instance of tkinters `IntVar` and to *get* the value we need to use the method `get()`.

Comment: the problem has resolved
thanks for your help
i have 8 records on the database
but the treeview show only 7 records

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept this answer if it helped you out.

Comment: the problem has resolved ,
thank you,
but the treeview didn't show the three last items,
and how to accepet your answer?
am new here

Comment: @AbdouKarim take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/tour